# Is there any danger if somebody knows my administrator password and has no physical access to my PC

Tags: networking, 18.04, password

I am coming from Windows. In Windows there is something called remove desktop access. If someday is in the same LAN he can access PC via Remote Desktop knowing my password.

Is it the same with default installation of Ubuntu 18.04?
If I am in the same room with many students (library) and type password and someday sees it, can he access my Ubuntu laptop? Everybody is connected to same WLAN and can see each other’s PCs through network.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, is the bottom line answer.
There have been a lot worse takedowns of major systems without passwords... so needless to say, with a password???

They will need, things like username, and access through services you may or may not have enabled. (ftp,ssh,http,rdp,or so on)... so it is 50/50 on that front...

But one would have to believe if someone obtains your password and wishes to enter your system, they have the key and will do so... and you should pretty much assume as much, always.

Comment: That means that I cannot use my computer in the library having this security feeling? Or is there any way to do so?

Comment: You have to be careful with your password and preferably change it regularly. If you have this strong feeling about security, it will be easy to have the same feeling about being careful about your password.

Comment: The VERY moment you suspect your password has been compromised, you should change it. Not just in this case at your school, this is an all-around philosophy. So just change the password and take away the feeling. Not to mention, just due to our nature (of all of us) when it comes to creating passwords, I am willing to bet that password will work on some other system in your life.

Answer (score -1):

By default ubuntu comes with no password. If somebody knows your private IP on that WLAN connection they could definitely SSH into your system. However, even if you did set a password and somebody knows it, they will still be able to ssh in your system. If they do NOT know your password, then not really! I hope this answered your question!

Comment: Many Ubuntu and Ubuntu flavor ISOs have passwords (even for an ISO in 'live' mode pre minstall, and it's set during install to whatever the user sets). Also many releases don't provide `openssh-server` by default (esp. desktop releases) so you can't `ssh` into them from a remote system anyway until the package is installed (the client only is provided by default for the majority of release/ISOs allowing you to `ssh` elsewhere only).